# Returning an array of objects from a query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I need a function for returning an array of services which each contains an *id* and a *name*. 
I've been looking in the mysqli documentation, but cannot verify if there exists smarter solution than this:

```
function getServices() {
    $services = array();

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM services WHERE client_id=?');
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $this->clientId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $service = array();
        $service['id'] = $id;
        $service['name'] = $name;
        $services[] = $service;
    }
    $stmt->close();

    return $services;
}
```

It seems a bit cumbersome that I have to build the resulting array myself. Is there a way to let mysql build the array using the selected columns?

Comment: I don't see any reasons why cannot this code be used. Even if the mysql-built version exists (which I doubt, but I'm not sure, I always used this way), there is no need to change.

Comment: @19greg96 - OP is using mysqli, not mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use mysqli, but from [inspecting the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), I believe this should work:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM services WHERE client_id=?');
$stmt->bind_param("i", $this->clientId);
$stmt->execute();

$result   = $stmt->get_result();
$services = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );

$stmt->close();

return $services;
```

Thus using:
1. [mysqli_stmt::get_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)
2. [mysqli_result::fetch_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

It is for PHP >= 5.3.0.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Sadly my server is running PHP 5.2 so the `get_result` method does not exist.

Comment: @DennisMadsen: Sorry to hear that. In that case you could perhaps extend `mysqli_stmt` and implement it yourself, if you think it's worth the effort. Or, indeed, use `PDO`, in stead of `mysqli` if you think it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to PDO, and you have the option of

[PDOStatement::fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: Seconded. You can pass fetch argument `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` to return an associative array. Lots of other options here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php